# Applying one page template to another page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to know how can I apply one page template to another page in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've been able to do this is open Designer - copy the page and paste it right back into the library - it will create a name like Page (2)...just change the page name and then you can edit it how you like.  You can copy and paste from one site to another too...but I don't think you can actually create a page template - just sites and lists..

Comment: Can I do the same thing but under Site Settings --> Site Content and Structure--> Actions--> Copy and to copy same page to the same page library in the same site?

Comment: Could you please answer can I do like I mention in above comment?

Comment: Personally I have never done it that way b/c I generally want to keep my content.  I say try it out.